# Why can I only edit my profile from the main site?

Tags: support, meta, profile-page

I was just about to edit my profile bio (from Meta) when I realised that the "edit" option isn't there,

[image: Meta screenshot]

But if I switch to my SO profile the edit option is back.

[image: SO Screenshot]

Is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your meta profile is a *copy* of the main site profile. You can only edit your profile on the main site, all changes are copied over to the child meta profile.

Comment: doesn't seem to be a big deal to allow editing from any place anyway :)